# como guardar el ID seleccionado de un radiobutton en una variable en lugar del value

Tags: javascript

tengo una serie de `radios` como los siguientes

```
  <input type="radio" name="registro[]" id="<?php echo $cartelera['sala'];  ?>" value="<?php echo $cartelera['id'];  ?>" required>
```

vienen de la base de datos con 10 `radiosbuttos`

tengo este codigo js

```
var valor = '';

$("input[name='registro[]']" ).on('change', function () {
    valor = $(this).val();
    alert(valor);
});
```

pero me trae el `value`, es correcto de cada `radio` pero no lo que ando buscando, yo necesito el `ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para obtener el código solamente cambia el ".val()" por ".attr("id")", así:

```
var valor = '';

$("input[name='registro[]']" ).on('change', function () {
    valor = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(valor);
});
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!

Comment: @kevinsauceda, si la respuesta es válida, puedes marcarla como tal haciendo clic en el *chekmark*. Saludos